# Calculate time difference in %H:%M:%S format in R

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format, difference

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between 2 columns for rows in which a certain criteria is fulfilled.

```
dates1 <- c("1899-12-31 12:20:00 PMT", "1899-12-31 15:30:00 PMT", "1899-12-31 13:20:00 PMT", "1899-12-31 11:50:00 PMT",
             NA)   

dates2 <- c("1899-12-31 11:13:00 PMT", "1899-12-31 11:41:00 PMT", "1899-12-31 14:04:00 PMT", "1899-12-31 13:03:00 PMT", 
            "1899-12-31 13:18:00 PMT")

site <- c(15, 16, 18, 18,
          15)

DS <- as.data.frame(cbind(site, dates1 , dates2))

## convert to POSIXct format
DS[, 2:3] <- lapply(DS[, 2:3], function(x) as.POSIXct(strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ",tz="")))

## create a new columns with the time difference between dates1 and dates2 in %H:%M:%S format if site=18 , else take value from column dates1
DS$output <- ifelse(DS$site ==18, 
                      difftime(DS$dates1, DS$dates2, units = "mins"),
                      DS$dates1) 

## using the code above doesnt work because:
#1- using the difftime function I can't choose the "%H:%M:%S" for the output
#2- for sites != 18, the dates1 lose its "%H:%M:%S format


# I have also tried to use:
DS$output <- ifelse(DS$site ==18, 
                      difftime(DS$dates1, DS$dates2, units = "mins"),
                      0) 
## and then convert the difference in minutes to %H:%M:%S format using
DS$output<- as.difftime(DS$output , format = "%H:%M:%S", units = "mins")

## but it doesnt work.

## the output should be something like:

output<- c("12:20:00", "15:30:00","00:44:00", "01:13:00", NA)

DS.out <- cbind(DS, output)

> DS.out 
  site                  dates1                  dates2   output
1   15 1899-12-31 12:20:00 PMT 1899-12-31 11:13:00 PMT 12:20:00
2   16 1899-12-31 15:30:00 PMT 1899-12-31 11:41:00 PMT 15:30:00
3   18 1899-12-31 13:20:00 PMT 1899-12-31 14:04:00 PMT 00:44:00
4   18 1899-12-31 11:50:00 PMT 1899-12-31 13:03:00 PMT 01:13:00
5   15                    <NA> 1899-12-31 13:18:00 PMT     <NA>

    #Where output is the time difference calculated for rows 3 and 4 (site=18) 
#or a copy of the time from dates 1 for the other rows (with sites different from 18).
```

Is there anyway to calculate time difference in H%:%M:%S format using a different function?

Comment: Have you considered the `lubridate` package?

Comment: I could not find the function to calculate the time difference in the format  H%:%M:%S  in lubridate

Comment: @RonakShah I just updated the example to include the expected output. I included a smaller dataset to make it easier to understand it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `hms` library.

```
require(hms)
x <- data.frame(TIME_SPENT = as.difftime(runif(10) * 10, format = 'H', units = 'hours'))
x$TIME_SPENT_HMS <- hms(hours = as.numeric(x$TIME_SPENT))

> x
      TIME_SPENT  TIME_SPENT_HMS
1  0.670335 hours 00:40:13.206023
2  6.740590 hours 06:44:26.122495
3  9.433242 hours 09:25:59.670743
4  9.350243 hours 09:21:00.873019
5  1.459504 hours 01:27:34.214544
6  4.820711 hours 04:49:14.560171
7  5.052186 hours 05:03:07.870653
8  9.415136 hours 09:24:54.489527
9  4.717802 hours 04:43:04.086949
10 4.131969 hours 04:07:55.087836
```

It supports objects of class difftime (but units are always seconds) and stores the values in HH:MM:SS format.

```
> class(x$TIME_SPENT_HMS)
[1] "hms"      "difftime"
```

You can perform all sort of calculations on it.

```
> x$TIME_SPENT_HMS[1] + 10
Time difference of 2423.206 secs
```

Values displayed in table view are also represented with semicolons:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use "times" format from chron library.

(this is not very straightforward but it seems to work)

```
# get the difference in minutes
DS$Time1NEW <- ifelse(DS$site ==18, 
                      difftime(DS$dates1, DS$dates2, units = "mins"),
                      NA) 

# get the absolute value
DS$Time1NEW<-abs(DS$Time1NEW)

# conver to hours:min:sec using "times" from library chron
DS$hours_minutes<-times((DS$Time1NEW%/%60 +  DS$Time1NEW%%60 /60)/24)

# convert the others (not in site 18)
DS$no18<-times(paste0(hours(DS$dates1),':', minutes(DS$dates1),':', seconds(DS$dates1)))

# create final data column
DS$final<-DS$hours_minutes

# now substitute when necessary
wh<-which(is.na(DS$final))
DS$final[wh]<-DS$no18[wh]
```

And this what you get:

```
> head(DS)
  site                  dates1                  dates2 Time1NEW hours_minutes     no18    final
1   15 1899-12-31 12:20:00 PMT 1899-12-31 11:13:00 PMT       NA          <NA> 12:20:00 12:20:00
2   16 1899-12-31 15:30:00 PMT 1899-12-31 11:41:00 PMT       NA          <NA> 15:30:00 15:30:00
3   18 1899-12-31 13:20:00 PMT 1899-12-31 14:04:00 PMT       44      00:44:00 13:20:00 00:44:00
4   18 1899-12-31 11:50:00 PMT 1899-12-31 13:03:00 PMT       73      01:13:00 11:50:00 01:13:00
5   15                    <NA> 1899-12-31 13:18:00 PMT       NA          <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: This is also a nice approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work ?

```
with(DS, ifelse(site == 18, as.character(lubridate::seconds_to_period(
                difftime(dates2, dates1, units = "secs"))), 
                format(dates1, "%T")))

#[1] "12:20:00"  "15:30:00"  "44M 0S"    "1H 13M 0S" NA
```

Comment: Yes but how do you convert the "44M 0S" to 00:44:00? I need them all in the same format to do some analysis afterwards and the dataset is big

Comment: @AnaAntunes If you want to do analysis on them both the formats are not useful because they are just string. If you want everything in same format how about you change format of `dates1`? `with(DS, ifelse(site == 18, as.character(lubridate::seconds_to_period(
  difftime(dates2, dates1, units = "secs"))), 
  format(dates1, "%HH %MM %SS")))`

Comment: Yes the dates get all the same format. But if I want to change from "%HH %MM %SS" to "%H:%M:%S", how can I do it? If I use  format(DS$output,"%H:%M:%S") but it gave me an error: Error in format.default(other_site$Time1NEW, "%H:%M:%S") : 
  invalid 'trim' argument

Answer (score 0):

You could use `difftime` on hours; `floor` and `%% 1` of this give hours and minutes to be `paste`d together. Some rounding needed, though.

```
DS$output[DS$site == 18] <- {
  tmp <- as.numeric(round(with(DS[DS$site == 18, ], difftime(dates2, dates1, units="hours")), 2))
  paste(sprintf("%02d", floor(tmp)), round(tmp %% 1 * 60), "00", sep=":")
}
DS$output[site != 18] <- strftime(DS$dates1[DS$site != 18], "%T")
DS
#   site              dates1              dates2   output
# 1   15 1899-12-31 12:20:00 1899-12-31 11:13:00 12:20:00
# 2   16 1899-12-31 15:30:00 1899-12-31 11:41:00 15:30:00
# 3   18 1899-12-31 13:20:00 1899-12-31 14:04:00 00:44:00
# 4   18 1899-12-31 11:50:00 1899-12-31 13:03:00 01:13:00
# 5   15                <NA> 1899-12-31 13:18:00     <NA>
```